# How to pass password securely in EC2 bootstrap script?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-secrets-manager

I have an applications which I am trying to install via bootstrap script for EC2 instance. This application needs a password to be provided during the installation. What is the most secure way to provide the password during bootstrap process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended method is:

- Store the password in the [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/)
- Assign an **IAM Role** to the EC2 instance
- Grant **permissions** to the Role to access the secret in the Secrets Manager
- Add code to the startup script to **retrieve the secret from the Secrets Manager**

The code in the Startup Script will automatically use the permissions assigned to the role that was associated with the EC2 instance.

Comment: Found this answer while also looking. The biggest issue I've found with passwords in userdata is that anyone who has access to the server can view the password. This solution doesn't seem to solve this issue, as anyone who accesses this server can run the command to retrieve the secret - isn't it?

Comment: @WarrenG Yes. If somebody has the ability to login to the EC2 instance, then they can use any permissions associated with the IAM Role. General login access should be restricted on servers. In fact, some companies only allow servers to be deployed and updated through automated tools, and do not allow SSH/RDP access to production servers since it might result in untracked changes.

Comment: @WarrenG, why not set up two IAM roles - one with SecretsManager and EC2 permissions for bootstrapping, and another with standard operating level permissions that excludes those. The last step in the bootstrap script can be to use the AWS CLI to downgrade the role assignment for the new machine.